# Какое имя класса дать данному меню?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всю голову сломал, не могу придумать хорошее название класса этому меню, которое обведено зеленым.
Хотелось, чтобы по классу было понятно, что это именно этот блок меню. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

варианты:

`manager_menu`

`personal_menu`

`user_menu`

`profile_menu`

ну и менее понятные

`auxiliary_menu`

`overmenu`

Comment: Спасибо большое, аж несколько вариантов!